# MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, gevent

## Background

I've got a Django app that is heavily iobound, so per docs I've read, I'm trying to get gunincorn working  with gevent for the best performance.

## Error

```
dev1            | Patching Started
dev1            | /app/Dev/wsgi.py:19: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py)', 'urllib3.util.ssl_ (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)']. 
dev1            |   monkey.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
dev1            | Patching Done
dev1            | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:236: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
dev1            |   "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
dev1            | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py:38: MonkeyPatchWarning: Patching more than once will result in the union of all True parameters being patched
dev1            |   monkey.patch_all()
dev1            | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py:38: MonkeyPatchWarning: Patching more than once will result in the union of all True parameters being patched
dev1            |   monkey.patch_all()
dev1            | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py:38: MonkeyPatchWarning: Patching more than once will result in the union of all True parameters being patched
dev1            |   monkey.patch_all()
...
```

## Setup

wsgi.py

```py
# Needs to happen first
print("Patching Started")
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
# monkey.patch_all()
from psycogreen.gevent import patch_psycopg
patch_psycopg()
print("Patching Done")

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Dev.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Docker-Compose command

```yaml
    command:
      - |
        gunicorn Dev.wsgi:application  
        --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 
        --workers 10 
        --timeout 30 
        --preload 
        --access-logfile /dev/stdout 
        --worker-class gevent"
```

## Problem

So it seems to me that I should have my `monkey.patch()` in the right place when gunicorn picks it up in the very beginning, but somehow `urllib3.util` is loaded first.  Am I putting the monkey patch in the right place?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that you have a **gunicorn.conf.py** file. Did you try adding

```
monkey.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

at the top of this file?

It seemed to have worked for me, after having gone through the same issue that you just described. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I don't have a `gunicorn.conf.py` file, but I do have an `asgi.py` and I added that to it.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you. Out of curiosity, what worker are you using in your asgi.py file? Are you still using gevent or did you try any other ones such as uvicorn workers? I had some trouble setting uvicorn up.

Comment: oh, I actually never got gevent to work. I ended up bailing and using way more workers and threads in gthread which has worked very well so far for our heavily io bound app.

Comment: Interesting, for an IO bound app I would've expected better performance by using gevent, it being async. However must say that in my case it hasn't worked and our app is also heavily IO bound. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: oh, yea, if I could have gotten gevent to work, it would have been better.  I'll def try again when my current solution starts to show issues.  What issues are you having?

Comment: Was getting liveness/readiness errors when load testing EKS Fargate. Tried many combinations of gunicorn flags, increased pod cpu/mem resources (requests/limits). Eventuallyworked yesterday. Only diffs were 1) doubled limit wrt request resources. Funny enough in Fargate, limits and requests should be set to the same values according to documentation + take into account the extra 256MB because of kubelet etc on each Fargte node and 2) increased workers from 3 (1cpu x 2 + 1) to 5 workers (2 cpu x2 + 1) ...and it worked ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. I think I am going to reduce the limit again and see...